# What does the letter before 'for' in a for loop represent?

Tags: python

In the code:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    return [ n for n in args if n%2 == 0]
```

I always think of `n` as meaning 'anything', so why can't we just have  `[for 'anything' in args if 'anything' % 2 == 0 ]`

e.g. `[for n in args if n%2 ==0]`

Why do we need the `n` before the `for`? How should I think of this and why is it only sometimes required in a for-loop?

Comment: The `n` before `for` is the value that will be entered into the list you are creating.

Comment: There’s a difference between for loops (which this isn’t) and comprehensions (which this is).

Comment: Thanks, Sorry for my poor explanation, i was confused that any code using the 'for' keyword was classed as a For-loop. So the first 'n' represents the value to be added to the list, so you would only prefix a 'for' keyword regardless of a loop or list comprehension if you were looking to 'add' to a list then!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "I always think of `n` as meaning 'anything'". What you're looking at is a list-comprehension, not a for-loop. They have different syntax. You have to parse it mentally like this:

1. For every item in my collection, where the current item will be called `n` (`for n in args`)
2. Add `n` to the list I'm generating... (The step where you're
   confused)
3. ...only if some condition is true (`n%2 == 0`. This filtering is
   optional)

For example, take a look at this list-comprehension:

```
>>> [thing * 2 for thing in (1, 2, 3, 4)]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
>>>
```

1. For every item in my collection, where the current item will be
   called `thing` (`for thing in (1, 2, 3, 4)`)
2. Add `thing * 2` to the list I'm generating

Comment: Thanks, You totally get how i try to convert it to a logical sentence in order to learn. While i do understand what and how your telling me to visualise it, it also highlights why i was confused. In both your examples your start the sentence with 'For', which is natural, but then finish with the start of the code 'Add x', its the fact its back to front is why i was getting confused.

Comment: @StuPro I'm glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This called *list comprehension*. The `n` is the variable called n. when you type `n` before the `for`, it means that you want to add to the list the variable `n`. you could write for exmaple `n*2` and then it would add `n*2` instead of `n`, while `n` is an even number from `args`.
I would suggest you to read here more about [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension).
This can be translated into the next program:

```py
def myfunc(*args):
  lst = []
  for n in args:
    if n%2 == 0:
      lst.append(n)
  return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've returned in the `return` statement is called list comprehension.

More generally, list comprehension could be explained as `[expression(element) for element in an_iterable if func_returning_bool(element)]`. Let's use this code snippet as a concrete example: `[n*n for n in [1,2,3,4] if n%2 == 0]`

The correspondence is as follows

- `expression(element)` <-> `element*element`
- `an_iterable` <-> `[1,2,3,4]`
- `func_returning_bool(element)` <-> `element%2==0`

We could break it down into several phases:

1. phase we find out the elements we are initially working on. It's actually the elements in `an_iterable`, namely `[1,2,3,4]`
2. phase we filter out the elements which satisfy the condition specified by `func_returning_bool`, only those elements are left after the filter phase. `[2,4]` is the result, because `func_returning_bool(1) == False` and `func_returning_bool(3) == False`.
3. phase the new list is constructed on the list `[2,4]` by substituting every element with `expression(element)`. Namely `[2*2, 4*4] = [4, 16]`

The second `element` in the code snippet is indeed "anything" in the list (after filtering). But you could process the data retrieved from the list a step further by using a proper `expression(element)` (if you need to). If you do not need to process the data further, you need to at least write `element` as the expression.

Comment: Thanks, Having read through the previous answers, im now able to understand your explanation.